# Inserting multiple rows to mysql table from csv file

Tags: mysql, csv

I am using the following query to upload data to mysql from csv file. The csv file has more than one columns separated as follow:

csv file:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

mysql query:

```
load data infile 'D:\abc.csv' INTO TABLE asdb.abc FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' lines terminated by '\n' (text,price);
```

the query inserts the values to the table, but at the end of last column of every row it inserts a strange symbol(couldnot post the screenshot as i am new to SO and dont have reputation point,), after 2 and 4 a music like symbol is inserted.

Can anyone please suggest me how to remove that. Also is there any way to insert the values into the table where the csv file is like below:

csv file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Thanks, Biswa

Comment: check Yours collation, or after insert run `replace` command if all the time is the same sign ;)

Comment: it's just for test: try ` lines terminated by '#\n'` (wgere # is music sign)

Comment: didnot work out for me